# Why distributions as functionals?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, schwartz-distributions

Why do we generalize functions by functionals on Schwartz Spaces, beyond the fact that it simply works? There should be a deeper reason why Schwartz considered **functionals**.
Excited for answers, Alex.

Comment: I voted to close because it seems to discussiony, but maybe I was mistaken to do that.  There could be some really good answers to this question.

Comment: I think fundamentally, it comes down to the philosophy embodied by the yoneda lemma.  To understand "blah" look at its relationship to all other things, or maybe just one particular thing.  Often such a representable functor captures ALL data about a thing.  Then generalized blahs come from functors which were not representable to start with.  In other words, studying the category of presheaves on a given category is almost always worthwhile.

Comment: ...hmm ...and what does it meanin this case?

Comment: These objects appeared naturally long before Schwartz made them rigorous.  See the history section of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_Delta_function for motivation.  There are other generalizations, e.g., hyperfunctions, so Schwartz's solution is not unique by any means.

Comment: Although closed: There is a fundamental physical motivation for distributions which is nearly explained in Strichartz book "A Guide to Distribution Theory and Fourier Transforms", chapter 1. In a nutshell: If $f$ shall represent a physical quantity (like temparature, pressure,…) then it does not seem plausible from a physical point of view to talk about values of $f$ and some point $x$ because true point measurements are not possible. However, averaged measurements are possible and this gives rise to testing the quantity against functions and there you are.

Comment: Ah sheesh, it should read **neatly** (not "nearly") in the first sentence.

Comment: In fact, one need not emphasize generalized functions (a.k.a. distributions) as "functionals", but as elements of the completion of Schwartz functions with respect to the weak *-topology, showing that they _extend_ Schwartz functions, emphasizing this extensions property rather than the duality.

Comment: @Dirk: And this averaging procedure is _linear_ just because...

Comment: @Alexander Shamov: That's some point... But well, "average" sounds pretty linear to me. More practically: A light sensor is basically collecting all the light that hits it and hence, measures the average (in the sense of arithmetic mean) light in that region. I do not know enough about other sensors but linearity sounds very reasonable to me.

Comment: @Dirk: Well, the way that quantity affects the measurement device is quite complicated and nonlinear, right? Of course we can argue that "everything is approximately linear unless it's too large", but isn't the whole point of distributions to capture things that are exactly "too large", i.e. "singular"?